# Find neighbour tuples

Tags: python, data-mining

I'm looking for a algorithm but miss the right keywords to get an overwiew. What I try to realize is a function that finds correlations/patterns/... in a dataset of tuples (simplified). For example:

```
dataset=(('a','b','c'),('1','a'), ('x','y','b','c'))
print magic(1.0, dataset)
-> ('b','c')
```

As you see, the function should return pairs of elements, that always appear together (1.0 = 100%) or with a specific propability.

Can anybody please tell me which group of algorithms will suite for my problem? Maybe pointing to a lib that does the work and is tested? :)

Comment: What probability corresponds to `('a', 'b')`? What about `('b', 'a')`?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: `that always appear together` -> Sounds like you want to classify on [Bayes theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem); find support between B and C.

Comment: @shuttle87 no. Relevant is a differnt subtask: frequent itemset mining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at **Frequent Itemset Mining (FIM)** and **Association rule mining**.

In your question, you are essentially interested in association rules of the type `A -> B` with confidence 100%.

In particular, the [APRIORI algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm), if you are interested in cooccurrences larger than 3.

Note that if you only want pairs, APRIORI boils down to scanning your database twice to count all pairs; you don't gain anything by pruning. Depending on the sparsity of your data, intersecting inverted lists can be much much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the hints :) As implentation I found the orange lib that offers different falvours: http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate/